# Apply a filter from a Date Filter web part that was set with JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, filter, datepicker

I have a Date Filter web part that is connected to a list. I can set the content of the filter with jQuery, but how can I get the filter to apply itself when I set the value this way?

Normally you just enter a date and it applies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value yourself (with a mouse click) you send a click event.

So you have to do that click event with code

`<option>` does not have a click event handler, you have to *click* on the `<select>`

```
$([filterelement]).click()
```

Comment: I don't that is for a Date Filter? Date filter has an input and a datepicker widget thing.